# Integration with redux does not work when screens and navigators are defined as functions in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In react-navigation module of React Native you can define your screens like `screen: props => <SignOutScreen {...props} />`, and pass up navigators as export `default (props) => <RootNavigator {...props} />`
You may want to do it to pass extra props and as far as navigation itself is concerned it is working fine.

But when you wire up redux as described in the docs everything breaks with different errors like cant' get getStateForAction of undefined and others.
I have not seen in the official docs that you can define screens like functions but I see folks are doing this so you need either make sure it works with redux as well, or state that this feature is unofficial and does not support at least redux integration.

The guys from react navigation closed this issue 5 mins after openning presumably to keep the issue number low.

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2923#issuecomment-342471629

if anyone tried to use redux with screens as function please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: They closed the issue on GitHub, because: "It looks like this is not a bug of the library nor a feature request".

Comment: Why would you define screens as functions instead of following the described pattern in the docs?

Comment: There are 3 reasons for that:
1. in their git repo discussion someone offered this solution to a request to pass some props to the screen
2. Amazon official mobile boilerplate uses this approach
3. It would be a very elegant solution eliminating the need for extra components